# Unable to switch to integrated GPU, using fglrx, Catalyst 12.6, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: radeon, intel, fglrx, catalyst, switchable-graphics

recently I installed proprietary drivers from ATI,

but I am unable to switch to integrated GPU

- using **console**

  ```
  sudo amdconfig --px-igpu
  sudo restart lightdm
  ```

  i am able to log in, but then system shows only background image

  and mouse cursor (which moves, but does not interact)
- using **Catalyst Control Center**

  system hangs and mouse moves choppy

My system configuration:

HP 4330s

Intel i5 2410M

ATI Radeon HD 6490M

Catalyst 12.6

Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

This should be kind of fixed in Ubuntu 12.10.

There are a couple of other bugs, though, so you might want to follow the instructions here:
[Can't install ATI proprietary drivers in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10/207270#207270)